# How to F5 deploy with add-in libraries in Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, reference, msbuild, project

I maintain an application with some project references it depends on. Further on, there are some "add-in" projects in the same solution which aren't needed to compile the application, but are loaded at run-time. Nevertheless, the "add-in" projects are vital for the application to do its work. That is, they are *mandatory* add-ins.

My team shall always be able to launch the application using Visual Studio, doing an incremental build as necessary, with the add-in libraries deployed to the application.

The add-in projects don't share their output directory with the application project since the add-in projects are AnyCPU, while the application is build for the x86 and x64 platforms.

I hesitate to simply add P2P references to the add-in projects. Not having the P2P references is not only a good way to communicate the add-in character of those projects, it also helps IntelliSense to not become overwhelming.

I tried to [use P2P references with `ReferenceOutputAssembly` set to `false`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kirillosenkov/2015/04/04/how-to-have-a-project-reference-without-referencing-the-actual-binary/), but this seems to not support incremental build inside Visual Studio.

So, in presence of the above mentioned real-world constraints, how can I provide a satisfactory F5-experience?

Answer (score 3):

Use P2P references with `ReferenceOutputAssembly` set to `false`, but consider the following pit-falls:

- As things are now with Visual Studio 2017 version 15.4.2 and earlier, the fast up to date check doesn't support this feature. Therefore, disable the check by setting the `DisableFastUpToDateCheck` property to `true` in the application project, as described in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-properties). This is likely to substantially increase build time.
- Don't specify the `CopyToOutputDirectory` metadatum in the project reference in case the output directory of application and referred project coincide. Otherwise, this brakes the `Rebuild` target.

Answer (score 1):

> So, in presence of the above mentioned real-world constraints, how can I provide a satisfactory F5-experience?

If I understand you correct, I am afraid you have entered a misunderstanding. Using P2P references with `ReferenceOutputAssembly` set to `false`, Visual Studio/MSBuild will not copy that reference library to the output of reference project, but the referenced project will still be compiled.

If you do not want to compile those "add-in" projects in the same solution, but  load them at run-time, you can reference the `.dll` file directly of those "add-in" projects. Or you can package your Library assemblies with NuGet. You can then use NuGet in Visual Studio to take care of all these references. In those case, the "add-in" projects aren't compile, but are loaded at run-time.

If you just want not copy those libraries of "add-in" projects into the output directory for reference project, you can set the property "`Copy Local`" of those references to false.

**Update for comment:**

> I'd like to develop the "add-in" projects in the same solution. Do you advise against this workflow?

The simple answer is yes. If you develop the "add-in" projects in the same solution, when you make any modification in the referenced project, the reference project will be recompile, which will destroy your previous deploy.
So I do not recommend develop the "add-in" projects in the same solution, you can move it to a new solution. If you still want to develop that projects in the same solution, you can refer to my previous advice "package your Library assemblies with NuGet. You can then use NuGet in Visual Studio to take care of all these references.". In this case, the previous deploy would not be destroyed When you develop add-in project.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations. Setting `ReferenceOutputAssembly` to `false` has the effect of not linking against the project. In order to copy it, one has to specify two additional metadata, as explained in the blog entry I referred to in my question. However, if I change something in the add-on project, it will get compiled yet not copied over.

Comment: I'd like to develop the "add-in" projects in the same solution. Do you advise against this workflow?

Comment: @tm1, I have updated my answer for your comment, you can check if it give you some help. If yes, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues. If not, please let me know for free, I will keep follow it.

Comment: I revised the question to describe better the nature of the add-in projects, which may better indicate the wish to develop them in the same solution as the main project.

Comment: If develop "add-in" in the same solution is necessary, I can think of the way is packing your Library assemblies with NuGet.

Answer (score 0):

Just use P2P references everywhere to make it work. That is, prefer a working build system over the cosmetics of not directly having referenced the "add-in" projects.

Comment: thanks for sharing your solution here, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues.

Comment: @Leo-MSFT I'd like to mark an answer based on community feedback. As it stands, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47132155/806690) answer works fine for me, but others might have had different experiences.